# How to create a .war file from this .war folder?

Tags: eclipse, war

All I have right now is a folder called ProjectName.war that, once upon a time, was deployed FROM an actual .war file. But I do not have the .war file itself, I only have the folder which has the same name.

This folder has the WEB-INF, META-INF, and custom code inside it.

I just need to know how to take the contents of this folder and re-create a .war file that can be used for deployment.

I have Eclipse available to me, but I have never used it before. So I'm not sure how to upload the code into Eclipse. I can't use "Import > WAR" because I don't have the actual .war file.

Can anyone advise me on what I need to do in order to take this folder and create a .war file? Thanks!

Comment: cant you just zip it and rename that zip to a `.war`?

Comment: What @RickyA said.  A WAR file is just a ZIP file with a specific folder structure.  You already have the folder structure, so...